# Transfering files from former M.2 SSD with former windows files to the newer drive with clean installed windows which is used for boot?

Tags: usb, ssd, windows-11

I currently have Windows 11 installed on a 256GB SAMSUNG PM991 M.2 SSD whose capacity is not enough for me. I bought 1TB SAMSUNG 980 M.2 SSD, which I was going to use to clone the 256GB one, but because of the 256GB drive being so crowded; I decided to do a clean installation on the 1TB drive instead. The problem is, I will have to transfer some of my files. I know that I can transfer them from an USB disk, but I am afraid that I will forget some files.

**First question is;**

- Is it possible to plug the M.2 SSD through USB port without any problem? (due to the nature of M.2 SSD's being exposed to environment)

**If the first question is possible, the second question is;**

- Does the 256GB SSD have any chance to corrupt the windows that will have been installed on the 1TB drive?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to recover your files.

(1) Get a carrier, put the M.2 drive in the carrier, attach and take ownership of the files.

Sample carrier shown.

I have done this and not corrupted any files. The new install has a slightly different internal User identifier.

[External carrier for M.2 SSD Drive](https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=enclosure%20for%20m.2%20nvme%20ssd&gclid=CjwKCAiAk--dBhABEiwAchIwkSzOwx9Zpmq4TVQdIIHlC5gd-qP4p57JPF3Uw6YpwMtVK36YaWfedRoCpIgQAvD_BwE&hvadid=604589631978&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=1002350&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=7282157341349736913&hvtargid=kwd-791720093219&hydadcr=25137_13540603&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_37wdbq933f_e)

(2) It may be easier overall to temporarily remove the 1 TB drive and reinstall the 256 GB drive.

Start up, copy everything you need to a USB drive.

Reinstall the 1 TB drive and collect your files.

I use and prefer this method because it is simpler overall and allows you to get everything you want.

Comment: Thank you so much :)